# nifi Json data using routeonattributeto filter attribute or attribute value

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, data-ingestion, hortonworks-sam

I am currently working to consume data using Nifi to read tealium event stream and load into HDFS. Need help in filtering the data when source misses to send data for attribute.

{"account":"newtv","twitter:description":"Discover when your favorite NewTV shows and hosts are being shown. ","og:locale":"en_US","dcterms:publisher":"NewTV","original-source":"www.newtv.com/","og:url":"www.newtv.com/show/program-guide"}},"post_time":"2019-10-09 11:27:46","useragent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36","event_id":"12345"}

Sample above message. I am currently stuck with filtering the data when source misses to send data for event_id attribute from the following sample dataset.

Current Nifi flow,
Consume Kafka -> Evaluate Json Path -> Jolttransform Json -> Evaluate Json Path-> RouteOnAttribute -> Merge Content -> Evaluate Json Path -> Update attribute -> PutHDFS ->MoveHDFS

Need help how to split data using RouteOnAttribute to differentiate missing event_id attribute or attribute_value to two different flows. Flow with attribute or attribute value and missing values to error and load into different output path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `EvaluateJsonPath` processor add new property to extract `event_id` value from the flowfile.

if flowfile is not having `event_id` then nifi adds empty value to the attribute.

**`EvaluateJsonPath Configs:`**
[image]

Then by using `RouteOnAttribute` processor we can check the attribute value and route the flowfile accordingly.

**`RouteOnAttribute Configs:`**

not null value

```
${event_id:isEmpty():not()}
```

null value

```
${event_id:isEmpty()}
```

[image]

Then use null value and not null value relationships for further processing..!!

Comment: Thanks for the response Shu. I have fixed the issue.